# Get std::function from template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am trying to implement some kind of task-class that will be done after some time. Currently I have to implement class, say for example TimeoutTask (needed for the bigger task). In it's body I want to get std::function from template parameters and this function I will call after some extra logic. The problem is that I can't properly "create" this function. But I can call it directly. Where is the problem? (I haven't use templates too much before, just simple ones)

```
class TimeoutTask
{
public:
    template <class Class, class Method, class... arguments>
    TimeoutTask(int timeout, Class *obj, Method f, arguments&&... args)
    {
        // here I get error: error C2059: syntax error : '<tag>::*'
        std::function<std::result_of<decltype(obj)(Class)>::type(arguments...)> 
            task(Class::*Method, obj, std::bind(std::forward<arguments>(args)...));

        // here will be some extra logic
        // and after this extra logic I want to call 'task' somehow

        // but I can call it just by this way:
        (obj->*f)(args...);     
    }
};
```

And code for creation of this "task":

```
SomeClass sc;
TimeoutTask testTask(1000, &sc, &SomeClass::someMethod, 101);
```

Comment: You don't need `std::function` from given code.

Comment: `typename` should be missing.

Comment: You may use intermediate type btw, something like `using Ret = decltype((obj->*f)(std::forward<arguments>(args)...)); std::function<Ret(Class*, arguments...)> task {f}; task(obj, std::forward<arguments>(args)...)`

Comment: Yeap, I didn't really needed std::function. Even more, I redesigned classes for my purpose. Should this question stays here or I should delete it?

Comment: If it is not needed I would just delete it